# Vue.js + Typescript: Why is v-model not recognised as value?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

## Problem

I got the following error in my Vue.js + TypeScript project:

```
<my-input> misses props: value
```

## Component Definition

I followed the Vue.js documentation on the usage of `v-model` on components as described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components).

### MyInput.vue

My component for which I want to use the `v-model` keyword looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class MyInput extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true }) private readonly value!: string;
}
</script>
```

### MyFirstView.vue

I now want to use `myInput` component in the following way:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <my-input v-model="myValue" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import MyInput from '@/components/MyInput.vue';

@Component({
  components: { MyInput }
})
export default class MyFirstView extends Vue {
  myValue = 'my test value';
}
</script>
```

## Questions

So accordingly to the official documentation the usage of `v-model` in `my-input` resolves to this:

```
<my-input v-bind:value="myValue" v-on:input="myValue = $event" />
```

So I obviously set the `value` property with the `v-model` keyword, right? But why do I get that error that the `value` prop wouldn't have been set?

When I change the `required` keyword to `false` the error vanishes but this can't be the right solution, right? Because I want the `value` property to be required.

---

Used IDE: VSCode with ESLint+Prettier and Vue.js 2.6.11

Comment: I also get this error, but only in VSCode. I don't see this error with `npm run build` or `npm run serve` on the command line.

Comment: @smeier_ec so my code is actually correct?

Comment: I would say so. I have no idea why VSCode suddenly shows these error messages though (I'm pretty sure it didn't a few weeks ago).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in Vetur, fixed in https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/pull/2241  Update Vetur to v0.27.2 or later.